# How to print string to console Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am really new to Yii2 and I am trying to print a simple string to the console. However, no matter what I do, I can't really make it work. I am not sure if I have my Setup wrong or if I simply don't use the functions as intended.

My `TeamController.php` was generated by `Gii` and the function I want to simply check if my code runs through looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Team;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\log\Logger;
use yii\helpers\VarDumper;

    /**
     * Creates a new Team model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        VarDumper::dump('Hello world'); //<-- Does not print to console.
        Yii::debug('start calculating average revenue'); //<-- Does not print to console.
        $model = new Team();
        if ($this->request->isPost) {
            if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'idteam' => $model->id]);
            }
        } else {
            $model->loadDefaultValues();
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Changed some configurations in the `web.php` within the config directory.:

```
'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning', 'trace', 'info'],
                    'logVars' => [],
                    'logFile' => '@runtime/webapp/logs/myfile.log',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Am I forgetting something or are other configurations wrong?

Comment: What kind of console do you mean?

Comment: A `-zsh` console. In Yii1.1 i used `Yii::log()` to print stuff to the console and used `docker-compose logs -f <container>` to actually see the print in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set `flushInterval` and `exportInterval`

```
'log' => [
    'flushInterval' => 1, // <-- here
    'targets' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
            'levels' => ['error', 'warning', 'trace', 'info'],
            'logVars' => [],
            'logFile' => '@runtime/webapp/logs/myfile.log',
            'exportInterval' => 1, // <-- and here
        ],
    ],
]
```

sourse: https://yii2-cookbook-test.readthedocs.io/logging-problems-and-solutions/

Comment: Thank a lot for the help. I have already tried this out but it does not seem to work. I think I just might give up. It seems I am simply unable to make it work no matter what.

Comment: Never mind. I made a typo in the `flushInterval` and did simply not see it. It work perfectly now.